# Python-Pandas: How do I create a create columns from rows in a DataFrame without redundancy?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Joined multiple DataFrames and now I got only one DataFrame. Now I want to make the same ID rows to columns without redundancy. To make it clear:

The DataFrame that I have now:

```
        column1   column2   column3
row1      2          4         8

row2      1          18        7

row3      54         24       69

row3      54         24       10

row4      26         32       8

row4      26         28       8
```

You can see that I have two row3 and row4 but they are different in column2 and column3

This is the DataFrame that I would like to get:

```
        column1   column2   column3    row3_a    row4_a
row1      2          4         8        NULL      NUll

row2      1          18        7        NULL      NULL

row3      54         24       69         10       NULL

row4      26         28       8         NULL      28
```

Any ideas how should I solve this?

Comment: Can you provide the data as dataframe constructor?

Comment: Yes I can and I already did

Comment: This is not a DataFrame constructor (`df = pd.DataFrame(...)`) ;)

Comment: Which constructor should I use then?

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird reshaping as you will have ambiguity if there are also duplicates in column1 or column2. Thus having a MultiIndex is probably a good solution.

This solution reshapes using a combination of `melt` + `drop_duplicates` and `pivot`

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
letters = dict(enumerate(ascii_lowercase, start=1))

# add a/b/c to duplicated rows
suffix = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().map(letters)
idx2 = (df.index+suffix).fillna('')

df2 = (
 df.assign(row=idx2)
   .reset_index()
   .melt(id_vars=['index', 'row'])
   .drop_duplicates(['variable', 'value'])
   .pivot(index='index', columns=['variable', 'row'], values='value')
   .rename_axis(columns=(None, None), index=None) # cleanup index names
)
```

output:

```
     column1 column2       column3      
                     row4a         row3a
row1     2.0     4.0   NaN     8.0   NaN
row2     1.0    18.0   NaN     7.0   NaN
row3    54.0    24.0   NaN    69.0  10.0
row4    26.0    32.0  28.0     NaN   NaN
```

You can flatten the multiindex if you want: `df2.columns = df2.columns.map(''.join)`, of if really you want your ambiguous names: `df2.columns = df2.columns.map(max)`